# Как перенести проект Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

Я написал программу и скомпилировал ее в EXE.
После того как я решил протестить ее(на старом(очень старом) ноутбуке) я столкнулся с проблемой которую вы можете наблюдать на скриншоте.
Погуглив нашел только одну причину (возможно плохо гуглил) и это отсутствие microsoft visual studio c++.
Так вот мой вопрос.
Возможно ли запустить python на компе без microsoft visual studio c++(но желательно без установки Интерпретатора) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S Если интересует код программы то: print("hello"); input()

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96586/discussion-on-question-by-artur----python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.5 (и выше) не поддерживает Win XP, см. https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/:

> Python 3.5.0 - Sept. 13, 2015
>   **Note that Python 3.5.0 cannot be used on Windows XP or earlier.**

Такая приписка у всех новых версий Python.

Попробуйте Python 3.4.4 x86 версию (не x86-64) (или более новую версию ветки 3.4, но тогда придется собирать Python из исходников).

Стандартный CPython не компилирует код - максимум ваш код и кусок интерпретатора собирается в один exe файл (так работают PyInstaller и cx-freeze, например. nuitka транслирует код в Си, но кусок интерпретатора в виде python35.dll все равно нужно будет таскать вместе с exe файлом). Поэтому нужно установить Python 3.4, на него PyInstaller (или чем вы пользовались), после этого уже собирать exe.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) поможет. Он позволяет собрать всё нужное и тогда необходимость в установке интерпретатора отпадает.

[Здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/325626/) на русском расписано всё, что нужно для быстрого старта.